# Will the authority accept my second ticket as a confirmation that I am transiting

Tags: air-travel, transit, covid-19, spain

I booked two ticket from two different companies.

The first ticket is from Germany to Barcelona, arrives in the morning. The second is from Barcelona to non-Eu country departs at night.

Spain currently does not require any tests when going there for a transit. When they ask me for my corona test, will they accept my second ticket as a confirmation that I'm going there for less than 24h without going outside the airport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is allowable:

From: https://www.spth.gob.es/faq?tab=2

> If the transit in Spain is carried out without leaving the international zone, you will not be required to present a AIDT. If the transit involves passing through border control centres and therefore entry into Spanish territory, they must present the boarding card or purchase ticket for the next flight or flights of the connection to demonstrate that the final destination is international, and they may continue their journey, provided that the transit lasts less than 24 hours and they do not leave the airport premises.